# C#: Accounting for datatype length specification

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code as part of my data access layer.

```
    #region Update ConnectionType
    public void UpdateConnectionType(string lastUpdatedBy, string connectionTypeDesc, int connectionTypeID, bool isDisabled)
    {
        var sqlStatement = new StringBuilder();
        sqlStatement.Append(" UPDATE dbo.ConnectionType");
        sqlStatement.Append("   SET");
        sqlStatement.Append(" LastUpdatedBy = @LastUpdatedBy, ");
        sqlStatement.Append(" ConnectionTypeDesc = @ConnectionTypeDesc,");
        sqlStatement.Append(" IsDisabled = @IsDisabled, ");
        sqlStatement.Append(" LastUpdatedDate = GetDate() ");
        sqlStatement.Append(" WHERE ");
        sqlStatement.Append("   ConnectionTypeID = @ConnectionTypeID");

        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement.ToString());

        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ConnectionTypeID", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlCommand.Parameters["@ConnectionTypeID"].Value = connectionTypeID;

        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@IsDisabled", SqlDbType.Bit);
        sqlCommand.Parameters["@IsDisabled"].Value = isDisabled;

        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@LastUpdatedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        sqlCommand.Parameters["@LastUpdatedBy"].Value = lastUpdatedBy;

        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ConnectionTypeDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        sqlCommand.Parameters["@ConnectionTypeDesc"].Value = connectionTypeDesc;

        DBAccess.SQLServer.ExecuteNonQuery(DBAccess.SQLServer.GetConnectionString("AccountTracker"), sqlCommand);
    }
    #endregion
```

The code above is pointing to a database where the datatype for the `ConnectionTypeDesc` is `varchar(100).` As of right now I only indicate that it is of type varchar.

My question is: How should I account for the difference in datatype specification?

- Should I create an object class using some the example code below?

  ```
      // SQL parameter collection
      var sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>();

      sqlParams.Add(new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Client_Code", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Size = 9, Value = clientCode });

      // Create sql command
      var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement.ToString());

      // Add sql parameters to sql command
      sqlCmd.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams.ToArray());

      // Execute sql
      DBAccess.SQLServer.ExecuteNonQuery(DBAccess.SQLServer.GetConnectionString("JutfDB"), sqlCmd);
  ```

Comment: Why are you using a `StringBuilder` to concatenate SQL? Just store it as a literal string.

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean with _difference in datatype specification_ Can you be more clear on this point? Why do you specify a size of 9 char in the second example?

Comment: The code you have is fine. If the connectionTypeDesc param of your method is a string that has a length over 100, then it will blow up so you may want to consider handling this error somewhere.

Comment: @Steve, the second example is just something I found relating to my code but it not specifically pointing to the fields I'm using. What I mean by datatype specification is that in the .netframe work my SQL parameter is passed as a string, I later convert it to a unspecified varchar type. In my database the field has a value of varchar(100).

Comment: @br4d, the string has no specified length. But is is later converted in the line setting the SqlDbtype = VarChar. The VarChar length is what I'm trying to specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the size of your varchar field then ALWAYS specify that size when you build your parameter

```
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ConnectionTypeDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
sqlCommand.Parameters["@ConnectionTypeDesc"].Value = connectionTypeDesc;
```

This has important effect on the performance of your query, in particular if you repeat it with a different value for `connectionTypeDesc` with a different string length.

The query optimizer in Sql Server could cache your query plan and reuse it if you call again the same query, but only if you have correctly specified the size of the varchar columns

You can read more about this issue in this article
[How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)

Comment: For future reference, the code that I had listed in the 2nd section of my question also works. The 2nd line of code essentially compacts the 2 lines in your answer into 1 line. Different ways to skin a cat, thanks for the article & answer!

Comment: Also, `sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ConnectionTypeDesc", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = connectionTypeDesc;`. Just not easily readable here on SO cause the limited code view area.